# What's the methodology for dealing with MacOS updates breaking npm and brew commands?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, homebrew, zsh

There's a new MacOS update and that means once I upgrade all my terminal commands like npm and brew are going to break (ie "zsh: command not found: brew"). What's the optimal way of dealing with this going forward into 2023? Do addons like oh-my-zsh and powerlevel10k affect it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Command not found" implies that the path to brew binaries got lost. A way to keep the paths is to add a file to `/etc/paths.d`:

```bash
cat <<EOF
$(brew --prefix)/bin
$(brew --prefix)/sbin
EOF > /tmp/homebrew
sudo mv /tmp/homebrew /etc/paths.d/
```

You can do the same for other paths.